# Measuring Voltage with Ground Bounce

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ground

So im trying to measure the voltage at output of an DC/DC converter, however I believe I am observing what is known as 'ground bounce'. Previously the converter was supplied a voltage from a wall wart, and the voltage at output could be measured easily with a multimeter.  The ON/OFF of the dc  converter is determinded by an arduino board. When the arduino asks for the voltage to be stepped up the voltage would read 0 before jumping up to 150 volts.

However I am now using a battery pack as a power supply. Here the voltage reads -40, and jumps to 60. As the -40 may be due to ground bounce can I take the actual voltage as 100? (difference between -40 and 60).

Not as much current is being drawn from the battery, so i would expect there to be not as much of a voltage increase. However I am concerned with measuring the increase, so can I take this as 100V?

Thanks

Comment: That would be a bit high for ground bounce, show some schematic, we have no idea what you are doing there.

Comment: Are you positive that the ground is connected?